# Django REST Framework - Return error if not allowed to view object not working?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a custom Django Rest Framework permission for one of my view, I only want Admins and the owner of the object to be able to view and edit the object, for everyone else return an exception error. But I can't get my custom permission to return an error if the request.user is not an Admin or the owner of the object.

Currently I have in my `view.py`

```
class ItemQuery(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
   queryset = Item.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ItemSerializer
   permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
   lookup_field = 'name'
```

and my `permissions.py`

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.basePermission):
   def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
       if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
           return True
       if obj.id.user = request.user or request.user.is_admin == True:
          return True
       else:
          return False
          response = exception-handler(self, request)
          response.status_code = 404
          return response
```

Comment: remove the last lines as they are never executed after the return False statement. Besides, the permission class should only return true or false and not a HTTP response. That is done by the view. Can you show the response you receive after you make a request as another user who is not the owner? From your code, it should work fine for POST and other unsafe methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
    return True
```

it returns before you check if owner or admin.